Describing the primes with each cyclic decomposition group in a given finite Galois extension of $\mathbb Q$
$\newcommand{\Q}{{\mathbb Q}}
$Let $f\in \Q[x]$ be a polynomial,
and let  $L/\Q$ be the finite Galois extension
obtaining by adjoining to $\Q$ all roots of $f$.
Magma knows how to compute $\Gamma:={\rm Gal}(L/\Q)$.
I am interested in algorithms and programs that can do the following:

(1) Find a finite set $S\ni\infty$ of places of $\Q$ such that the extension $L/\Q$ is unramified for all primes
$p\in\overline S:=V(\Q)\smallsetminus S$
(where $V(\Q)$ denotes the set of all places of $\Q$).


(2) For each cyclic subgroup $\Delta\subseteq G$, somehow determine all primes $p\in\overline S$ with decomposition group $D_p\subseteq \Gamma$ conjugate to $\Delta$.

Example. Let $f(x)=x^2+1$.
Then $L=\Q(\sqrt{-1})$ is unramified outside $\infty$ and $2$,
and by Fermat's theorem,
for $\Delta=\{1\}$ we obtain $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$,
while for $\Delta=\Gamma={\rm Gal}(L/\Q)$ we have $p\equiv 3\pmod 4$.
EDIT:
Motivation. I want to describe using computer the Galois cohomology set  $H^1(\Q,G)$ where $G$ is a connected reductive group over $\Q$. For this it more or less suffices to compute $H^1(\Q_v,G)$ for all places $v$ of $\Q$, and the Tate-Shafarevich kernel $Ш^1(\Q,G)$.
There is a program computing $H^1({\mathbb R},G)$ in my paper with Willem A. de Graaf. The other guys can be computed from the decompositions groups $D_p$ for all primes p. This motivates my question.

How would you like those sets of primes to be described? If the extension is not abelian they are not going to be given by congruences.

@Aurel: That's the point! I don't know how to describe those sets of primes. Is there any reasonable way to describe them?

@Aurel: See my edit (Motivation).

It sounds like you wish for an algorithm which would also calculate the Tate-Shafarevich group in case $G$ is an elliptic curve, that is known to be very hard (assuming the $G$ in the motivation is different than before). But (1) is clearly ok by taking away prime divisors of the discriminant of a version of $f$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.  (2) usually not, but sometimes. E.g if $K = \mathbb{Q}(E[\ell])$ for an elliptic curve $E$ and a prime $\ell$, then the Frobenius at a prime $p$ can be calculated from information of the reduction of $E$ modulo $p$.

@Aurel: I was not sufficiently clear! In my Motivation, the group $G$
is a connected reductive group.

I have edited the question and Motivation.
